# Statsmodel summary_col latex format error

Tags: python, latex

I am using the statsmodel's summary_col to give me an output table which summarizes the two regression output.

The code for this is

```
res3 = summary_col([res1,res2],stars=True,float_format='%0.2f',
              info_dict={'R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared)})
f = open('res3.tex', 'w')
f.write(res3.as_latex())
f.close()
```

I use the  res3.tex file as input for another tex file which then generates the results. The problem arises when i convert the table to LaTeX format using as_latex(). [The table header shifts to the side in the tex file and looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZmh8.png)

The res3.tex file has the following latex code

```
\begin{table}
\caption{}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \hline
        & investment I & investment II  \\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        GDP      & 1.35***      & 1.19***        \\
        & (0.24)       & (0.23)         \\
        bsent    & 0.28***      & 0.26***        \\
        & (0.06)       & (0.06)         \\
        rate     & -0.22*       & -0.65***       \\
        & (0.13)       & (0.19)         \\
        research &              & 0.80***        \\
        &              & (0.27)         \\
        R2       & 0.76         & 0.80           \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}\end{table}
```

The problem seems to arise due to multiple tabular environments. Is there a way to get the investment header on top of the table without manually changing the res3 file (intermediary file)?

Comment: If someone knows the fix for the required Latex, then an issue or pull request for statsmodels would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to add couple of things to Latex's preamble. 
Here you can probably find an answer to your problem [Outputting Regressions as Table in Python (similar to outreg in stata)?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11774/outputting-regressions-as-table-in-python-similar-to-outreg-in-stata).

```
res3 = summary_col([res1,res2],stars=True,float_format='%0.2f',
              info_dict={'R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared)})

beginningtex = """\\documentclass{report}
\\usepackage{booktabs}
\\begin{document}"""
endtex = "\end{document}"

f = open('myreg.tex', 'w')
f.write(beginningtex)
f.write(res3.as_latex())
f.write(endtex)
f.close()
```

All credits to @BKay